# Add HTTPS to intranet server

Tags: https, raspberry-pi, intranet

I am using a raspberry pi 3 to host an internal server on my cars wi-fi network. What I would like is for those connected to my network in the car to be able to access an intranet page with a map and stats about the trip's length, speed, ect. I am using Mapbox's GL JS library but the geolocation services requires a secure connection to function. Is there a way to ensure the connection between the intranet server (pi) and the user is secure so the location functionality can be enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer for your question will be that yes you can install SSL on raspberry pi use [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate) for that.

The long answer will be that you can't do that because you will have a problem with port 443 will [enabling it on the firewall](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/if-you-have-a-firewall-enabled-on-your-pi-open-port-443-if-you-get-timeouts-it-might-help/2445/5) and you will [suffer with it more](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/pull/961), but you may same how find a solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=84790)
or [here](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/4g-gps-lte-wcdma-hspa-3g-gprs-shield-arduino-raspberry-pi-waspmote-tutorial/) I hope so.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. The web-page will be hosted only on my local area network. I do not want those outside of the network to be able to access the webpage. users and the Raspberry-pi will share a common connection to a mobile router. Is there a way for me to enable secure communication or use a self signed certificate in this configuration?

Comment: maybe I really don't understand your question, so let me ask where you will host the ssl ? and what is the connection type that you will use ?

Comment: The raspberry pi will host the web server but I do not want to put the page onto the open web. I only want users on the same LAN as the server to be able to connect.

Comment: Good so you will put the ssl on the raspberry pi (Checked) then read suffer with it more.